# Variable Delimited Text in Excel

Tags: excel, delimiter

I have a string of text that I need delimited:
New Utilizers 75 28 9 66 66 79 74 69 29 21 84 75 675 20,511 45,925

Ordinarily I would just use a space delimiter and I'd be all set, but this splits the "New Utilizers" string into two columns instead of one. Is there a way to start delimiting after a certain point, in this case start after new utilizers

Comment: Just skip the first space?

Comment: Do you mean that you copy it from, say, a file and need to paste it into a single cell within the Excel?

Comment: If you don't want to keep the text at all you can skip the columns. Otherwise, add a column and concat.

Comment: All that text appears in one cell as it is one string

Answer (score 0):

Can you choise another delimiter? say $ or ;

if $ for example

New Utilizers$75$28$9$66$66$79$74$69$29$21$84$75$675$20,511$45,925

then split by $